# Looping over array contents to compare values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I thought I was doing everything right but I can't figure out why my code keeps returning false. When called with (inventory, and string) all I get is false although the values in varies.

Create a function called shouldWeOrderThisCandy that takes in the inventory array
a specific type of candy (string).

Return true if the number inStock is less than the weeklyAverage, otherwise, return false.

```
let inventory = [
  { candy: "Twizzlers", inStock: 180, weeklyAverage: 200 },
  { candy: "Sour Patch Kids", inStock: 90, weeklyAverage: 100 },
  { candy: "Milk Duds", inStock: 300, weeklyAverage: 170 },
  { candy: "Now and Laters", inStock: 150, weeklyAverage: 40 }
]
              

function shouldWeOrderThisCandy(inventory, []){
  for (i = 0; i < inventory.length; i++){
    if (inventory.weeklyAverage < inventory.inStock){
      return true;  
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
};
```

How do I return true?

Comment: Try `inventory[i].property` - you've referenced the array itself and not the value at index `i`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a problem in your code. Inventory is a list and you are accessing property using inventory.yourproperty which is incorrect. instead use like this and you should get correct result.

```
if (inventory[i].weeklyAverage < inventory[i].inStock){
 return true;
```

I tested and verified this code using C# language.

**Edited:**

Adding sample code here using C#

Model:

```
class Invenory
{
    public string candy;
    public int inStock;
    public int weeklyAverage;

}
```

Method:

```
void shouldWeOrderThisCandy()
    {
        List<Invenory> inventories = new List<Invenory>() 
                                        { new Invenory { candy= "Twizzlers", inStock= 180, weeklyAverage= 200},
                                        new Invenory { candy= "Sour Patch Kids", inStock= 90, weeklyAverage= 100},
                                        new Invenory { candy= "Milk Duds", inStock= 300, weeklyAverage= 170},
                                        new Invenory { candy= "Now and Laters", inStock= 150, weeklyAverage= 40} };

        foreach (var inventory in inventories)
        {
            if (inventory.weeklyAverage < inventory.inStock)
            {
                //write logic to add order
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks but now everything is returning true. i dont understand why

Comment: Test passed 
When called with (inventory, "Twizzlers")
expected:
true
got:
true.
Test passed 
When called with (inventory, "Sour Patch Kids")
expected:
true
got:
true.
Test failed. 
When called with (inventory, "Milk Duds")
expected:
false
got:
true.
Test failed. 
When called with (inventory, "Now and Laters")
expected:
false
got:
true.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's only returning true  when there are false statements as well

Comment: @MarayshaWashington try casting values into integer. And also I see a problem that your code will run only one time and loop will break returning either true or false. You should change the logic a little bit or I can help you if you can explain a little bit about your requirement.

Comment: thanks and i am trying to create a function called shouldWeOrderThisCandy (objects array, and specific string when called) i want to be able to compare objects within my array like the candy "inStock" and "averageWeekly" sales. if inSock is less than weekly sales i want to return true as in yes we need to order more candy. but false otherwise

Comment: @MarayshaWashington then I suggest not to write return true/false rather write logic to order more candy. This way your loop will run completely and for each candy if weekly candy is < than in stock candies, it will add more. Your current code will only execute for first object in array and will return true/false accordingly. You can mark it as answer if it clear your doubt.

Comment: @MarayshaWashington added sample code snippet for you. See if this resolves your problem. Code is written in C# but you can change it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure your meaning,
and I add a new column to store the result of every row.

```js
let inventory = [
    {candy: 'Twizzlers', inStock: 180, weeklyAverage: 200},
    {candy: 'Sour Patch Kids', inStock: 90, weeklyAverage: 100},
    {candy: 'Milk Duds', inStock: 300, weeklyAverage: 170},
    {candy: 'Now and Laters', inStock: 150, weeklyAverage: 40},
  ];
  
  function shouldWeOrderThisCandy (inventory, candy) {
    const row = inventory.find(item => item.candy === candy);
    if (row.weeklyAverage < row.inStock) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
  }
  
  console.log(shouldWeOrderThisCandy(inventory, 'Milk Duds'));
```

Comment: hello, I am trying to Create a function called shouldWeOrderThisCandy that takes in
the inventory array
a specific type of candy (string)  
Return true if the number inStock is less than the weeklyAverage, otherwise return false.

Comment: Does the new edited code be your expected ? @MarayshaWashington

Answer (score 0):

Yo have some errors in your code and you returning from loop immediately after first cycle, while you need to investigate each candy, if I get it right... Check code below, read comments

UPD: added method to specify only one candy

```js
const inventory = [
  { candy: "Twizzlers", inStock: 180, weeklyAverage: 200 },
  { candy: "Sour Patch Kids", inStock: 90, weeklyAverage: 100 },
  { candy: "Milk Duds", inStock: 300, weeklyAverage: 170 },
  { candy: "Now and Laters", inStock: 150, weeklyAverage: 40 }
]
          
const shouldWeOrderThisCandy = (inventory, str) => {
  // Set some object to store all DB values results
  const result = {};
  // Loop
  for(let i = 0; i < inventory.length; i++) {
    // If str exist, then skip everything else
    if(str && str !== inventory[i].candy) continue;
    // If in stock more then weekly avarage - do not order
    if(inventory[i].weeklyAverage < inventory[i].inStock) result[inventory[i].candy] = false;
    // If in stock less then weekly avarage - order
    else result[inventory[i].candy] = true;
  }
  // Return formed object
  return result;
}

// Log one element
console.log('Only one candy:');
console.log(shouldWeOrderThisCandy(inventory, "Twizzlers"));

// Log all
console.log('All candies:');
console.log(shouldWeOrderThisCandy(inventory));
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but shouldWeOrderThisCandy should be a function that takes in (the inventory array, and string from inventory like "Twizzlers" )  i want to verify whether inStock is less than weeklyAverage

Comment: Well here `true` means YES `inStock` is less than `weeklyAverage`. This is logically, because `false` itself does not mean less or something... So we need to take function name in attention - your function name is `shouldWeOrderThisCandy`, so this function should return `true` if YES we need to order (`inStock` < `weeklyAverage`) or `false` if NO we don't need to order.

Comment: UPD: added method to specify only one candy

Answer (score 0):

Hey there and welcome to StackOverflow! :)

The first problem here is that you never read the current object from the `inventory`-Array in your For-Loop, but you always try to access `weeklyAverage` on the array itself - which does not have this property. :)

Therefore, your if condition results in a comparison `undefined < undefined`.

This can be fixed by pulling out the value like so:

```js
function shouldWeOrderThisCandy(inventory, []){
  for (i = 0; i < inventory.length; i++){
    const currentCandy = inventory[i];
    if (currentCandy.weeklyAverage < currentCandy.inStock){
      return true;  
    } else {
     return false;
    }
  } 
};
```

However, this will always just check the first candy in your array and then immidiately return from the function, thus canceling your for-loop.

Not quite sure if you want that loop to check every candy or just one specific. But if you need the status for all Candy, you should not return in the for-loop, but save the values in an object, for example like this:

```js
function shouldWeOrderThisCandy(inventory, []){
  const candyNeedsOrderMap = {};
  for (i = 0; i < inventory.length; i++){
    const currentCandy = inventory[i];
    let needsOrder = false;
    if (currentCandy.weeklyAverage < currentCandy.inStock){
      needsOrder = true;  
    } 
   candyNeedsOrderMap[currentCandy.candy] = result
  } 
  return candyNeedsOrderMap;
};
```

However, if you need the value for one specific candy, you could achieve it like this:

```js
function shouldWeOrderThisCandy(inventory, candyName){
  const candy = inventory.find(current => current.candy === candyName);
  return candy.weeklyAverage < candy.inStock;
};
```

Comment: I still haven't figured this code out. i want the loop to loop through and find the value of inStock and also the value of "weeklyAverage" and if inStock is < than weeklyAverage  i want my string like "Skittles"  to return true. as in i need to order more of that candy. otherwise false if the string like "Chocolate" overstocked

Comment: Hm, I really don't quite understand your exepcted input and outcome. Maybe you can edit your question a bit and show the object you are actually expecting from the funcction? That would be very helpful.